# Reflexive Pronouns - MICH & DICH (cases)

Tags: reflexive

How can I know wether 'mich' and 'dich' should be in accusative or dative?

1. Hast du DIR gestern den neuen film gesehen?
2. Ich wasche MICH.

Why is the first one in DATIVE and the second one in ACCUSATIVE?

Comment: What are your doubts in particular, which aren't explained in your grammar textbook?

Comment: You'll have to memorize this for each verb, and in some cases even how the meaning (slightly) changes depending on case.

Comment: _"Hast du DIR gestern den neuen film gesehen?"_ is wrong BTW. Should be _Hast du DIR gestern den neuen film **an**gesehen?_

Comment: To add upon @Robert's comment, here's a [list](https://www.pons.de/daten/pdf/Praxis-Grammatik/04_Verben_mit_Dativ-_und_Akkusativobjekt.pdf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Hast du **dir** gestern den neuen *F*ilm *an*gesehen?

The verb **ansehen** takes an accusative object, which is the person or thing watched. Here, that's *den neuen Film*.

The pronoun *dir* is an addition, it's not required by *ansehen*. If you use it, it has to be **dative** because it's **the person or thing who receives something** – the impression from the movie.

---

> Ich wasche **mich**.

This one is very simple. The verb *waschen* takes an accusative object which is the person or thing washed. In this case, yourself.

BUT, some cases are tricky:

> Ich wasche **mir** die Hände.

Clearly, you are washing your own hands. But why is it *mir*, not *mich*? Because again, *die Hände* is the thing washed, and *mir* is a person who receives something - a hand wash in this case. You can wrap you mind around this with the following example:

> Ich wasche **dir** die Hände.

Now it's the other person who receives the hand wash.